# How do I configure boxen and rbenv with rubymine?

Tags: ruby, macos, rubymine, rbenv, boxen

I am trying to use Rubymine, which I have installed via boxen on my Mac OSX Mavericks.

The Jetbrains support indicates that Rubymine will look only in the default ~/.rbenv folder on startup. Is there a way to configure Rubymine to look at the boxen rbenv installation? Or do I need to link my ~/.rbenv directory to the rbenv directory under /opt/boxen?

The net result of using Rubymine without a ~/.rbenv directory on my machine is that it seems to be seeing only the system ruby versions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same issue when using rbenv with boxen.

But the easiest (hacky) solution is to just simlink the folder:

`ln -s /opt/boxen/rbenv/ ~/.rbenv`

Comment: I added a feature request to have this properly supported in the future: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-16035